# How to find the probability of only one of three events?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are three events $A, B, C$. 
Probabilities are 
$P(A\mid B)= 0.20,
P(C\mid B)= 0.4,
P\left((A \cap C)\mid B\right) = 0.1$
Given that $B$ has occurred
How to find only $C$ occur?

Comment: The title is different with the question. which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Given $B$ has occured, the probability of only $C$ means $C$ occur but not $A$ (since $B$ is occurred already), so it is $P(C\cap \overline{A}\mid B)$

$$P(C\cap \overline{A}\mid B)=P(C\mid  B)-P(C\cap A\mid B)=0.4-0.1=0.3$$

However, if you want the probability of $C$ only (among the tree events), given $B$, it is zero since it is impossible for $B$ to not occure when it is already ocurred! (regardless of $A$ and $C$) $$P(C\cap \overline{A}\cap\overline{B}\mid B)=0$$

Comment: If there are three events $A,B,C$ then I guess "only $C$" means the event $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}\cap C$ and so $P(\text{only }C\ |\ B)=0.$ Moreover the title says "only one of three events".

Comment: "Why is this post voted for delete?" You mean, the question? Two reasons that spring to mind are lack of context and mathematical ambiguity.